# Cannot compile ffmpeg for arm64 on Debian bookworm

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, debian

The title speaks for itself. Here's the log:

```
$ sudo dpkg --add-architecture arm64
$ sudo apt build-dep -a arm64 ffmpeg
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 builddeps:ffmpeg:arm64 : Depends: clang:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: glslang-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: ladspa-sdk:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libcdio-paranoia-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libomxil-bellagio-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libssh-gcrypt-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: libtesseract-dev:arm64 but it is not going to be installed
                          Depends: cleancss:arm64 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

sources.list:

```
deb https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main
deb-src https://deb.debian.org/debian bookworm main
```

What caught my attention is

`Depends: cleancss:arm64 but it is not installable`

`cleancss` is a javascript program and it's not even supposed to have an architecture-dependent package. What is it, some packaging bug? Or maybe I'm missing something?

**EDIT:** I don't know if it's important, but I'm following instructions from [Debian Wiki/CrossCompiling](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling), namely *Building with dpkg-buildpackage*. I already installed `build-essential` and `crossbuild-essential-arm64`. No, binary package won't work for me. Downloading, building and packaging everything manually is not an option either.

Comment: https://jensd.be/1126/linux/cross-compiling-for-arm-or-aarch64-on-debian-or-ubuntu

Comment: No, the title does not speak for itself. Please explain in as much detail what you are trying to accomplish. Is it, as ChanganAuto implies, cross-compiling _ffmpeg_ for your Raspberry Pi (or the like)? Are you perhaps following a guide/tutorial? If not, is there any particular reason you’re trying to use Debian packages to do it?

Comment: >Are you perhaps following a guide/tutorial?

https://wiki.debian.org/CrossCompiling Building with dpkg-buildpackage, whatever-essentials{,-arm64} already installed

>is there any particular reason you’re trying to use Debian packages to do it?

Well, cuz I want a ready-to-use Debian package rather than some unmanageable crap a standalone toolchain would produce. No, binary package is not an option (gotta apply patches otherwise some stuff I want working wont work). That doesn't matter anyway - I just want to know why the command fails.

Comment: Please make sure to [update your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1811785/edit) with all relevant clarifications.

Comment: I did `apt update` ofc